# Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hope someone can help me:

I have many sites running on my server and I am using mariadb.
when I do:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I get:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
```

> systemctl status mariadb.service

```
    mariadb.service - MariaDB database server

    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-09-14 03:16:51 UTC; 1min 6s ago
    Process: 13247 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=
    Process: 13086 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/gale
    Process: 13070 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, s
    Process: 13033 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, st
   Main PID: 13247 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─3803 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

> sudo journalctl -xe

```
   Sep 14 03:35:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
   -- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
   -- Defined-By: systemd
   -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
   -- 
   -- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
   -- 
   -- The result is failed.
   Sep 14 03:35:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
   Sep 14 03:35:51 ubuntu sudo[13566]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   Sep 14 03:35:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   Sep 14 03:35:52 ubuntu sshd[13753]: Failed password for root from 123.183.209.136 port 38816 ssh2
   Sep 14 03:35:52 ubuntu sshd[13753]: Received disconnect from 123.183.209.136 port 38816:11:  [preauth]
   Sep 14 03:35:52 ubuntu sshd[13753]: Disconnected from 123.183.209.136 port 38816 [preauth]
   Sep 14 03:35:52 ubuntu sshd[13753]: PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
   Sep 14 03:36:34 ubuntu sshd[13756]: Connection closed by 123.183.209.136 port 60477 [preauth]
   Sep 14 03:36:36 ubuntu postfix/pickup[12161]: 703AA5C0C5: uid=0 from=<root>
   Sep 14 03:36:36 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[12162]: 703AA5C0C5: message-id=<20170914033636.703AA5C0C5@ubuntu.me
   Sep 14 03:36:36 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[12162]: warning: 703AA5C0C5: write queue file: No space left on dev
   Sep 14 03:36:36 ubuntu postfix/pickup[12161]: warning: maildrop/5152F5C0C4: error writing 703AA5C0C5: queu
   Sep 14 03:37:17 ubuntu sshd[13760]: Received disconnect from 123.183.209.136 port 25567:11:  [preauth]
   Sep 14 03:37:17 ubuntu sshd[13760]: Disconnected from 123.183.209.136 port 25567 [preauth]
   Sep 14 03:37:36 ubuntu postfix/pickup[12161]: 7764B5C0C5: uid=0 from=<root>
   Sep 14 03:37:36 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[12162]: 7764B5C0C5: message-id=<20170914033736.7764B5C0C5@ubuntu.me
   Sep 14 03:37:36 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[12162]: warning: 7764B5C0C5: write queue file: No space left on dev
   Sep 14 03:37:36 ubuntu postfix/pickup[12161]: warning: maildrop/5152F5C0C4: error writing 7764B5C0C5: queu
   Sep 14 03:37:47 ubuntu sudo[13765]:      bob : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/bob ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journa
   Sep 14 03:37:47 ubuntu sudo[13765]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by bob(uid=0)
   lines 1238-1265/1265 (END)
```

I really don't want to lose my db.
What should I do next?

Many thanks

this is what df gives me:

```
   Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /dev/root       49362256 46854648         0 100% /
   devtmpfs         2019828        0   2019828   0% /dev
   tmpfs            2021768        0   2021768   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs            2021768    17968   2003800   1% /run
   tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs            2021768        0   2021768   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   tmpfs             404356        0    404356   0% /run/user/1000
   tmpfs             404356        0    404356   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: It seems your machine doesn't have free space to start MariaDB. Try to remove something if you have any temp file and restart again MariaDB

Comment: All sorts of things will croak when you use up all of `/`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a disk to the machine?  If so, you could move some items to the new disk, thereby freeing up some space on /.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear some space at root /.
Then try to restart mariadb.